# jquery slideshow won't iterate over dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, each

I found this Jquery slideshow snippet that works great for me except that it won't iterate over the DOM. Right now only the first slideshow in my document will work. I've searched all over and I am pretty sure I need to use .each() so that it will find all of the #slideframe DIVs in my document. Unfortunately I can't seem to use it properly. Any help in getting my portfolio up and running would be a great help!

you can see the "working" site here: [LINK](http://samkline.info/new.html)

Here is my JQUERY

```
<script language="javascript">    $(document).ready(function () {
    var count = $('#slideframe').children().length;
    $("#total").text(count);
    // set display:none for all members of ".pic" class except the first
    var hidden = $('#slideframe').children();
    $('hidden:gt(0)').hide();

    // stores all matches for class="pic"
    var $slides = $('#slideframe').children();

    $slides.click(function () {

        // stores the currently-visible slide
        var $current = $(this);
        if ($current.is($slides.last())) {
            $("#current").text("1");
            $current.hide();
            $slides.first().show();
        }
        // else, hide current slide and show the next one
        else {
            $("#current").text($current.next().index()+1);
            $current.hide().next().show();
        }

    });
});</script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="projectcontainer">
<div id="slideframe">
            <video class="image" src="NEW/PHOTOS/AW17_FW_INSTA_LOCKUP_LO.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop></video>
            <img class="image" src="NEW/PHOTOS/AW17_LONDON_SQUARE.jpg" style="display: none;">
            <img class="image" src="NEW/PHOTOS/AW17_MILAN_SQUARE.jpg" style="display: none;">
            <img class="image" src="NEW/PHOTOS/AW17_NEWYORK_SQUARE.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>


        <div class="imagetext">
            <div class="counter"><span id="current">1</span> / <span id="total">4</span></div>
            MAC Cosmetics AW17 Fashion Week Branding<br>
            ( Illustrations by <a href="culturesport.tv">culturesport.tv</a> )
        </div>
```

1 / 4
                MAC Cosmetics AW17 Fashion Week Branding
                ( Illustrations by culturesport.tv )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should only use one ID per DOM element. So, if you want to refer to multiple slideframe elements, consider using a class identifier, such as in the following example:

`<div class="slideframe">`

(Note you would also want to update the `#current` and `#total` elements so that their IDs are not duplicated either.)

Then, in jQuery you would reference these slideframes as follows:

`$('.slideframe')`

Also, to your point: you would want to iterate over both slideframes so that, for example, calls to `.last()` would be relative to the correct slideframe.

```
var $frames = $('.slideframe');
$frames.each(function() {
   var currentFrame = $(this);
   var currentSlides = currentFrame.children();
   currentSlides.click(function () {

        // stores the currently-visible slide
        var $current = $(this);
        if ($current.is(currentSlides.last())) {
            $(".current", currentFrame.next()).text("1"); // note this assumes you have set DOM element to use class="current"
            $current.hide();
            currentSlides.first().show();
        }
        // else, hide current slide and show the next one
        else {
            $(".current", currentFrame.next()).text($current.next().index()+1); // note this assumes you have set DOM element to use class="current"
            $current.hide().next().show();
        }

    });   
});
```

Comment: Ah! thank you so much!!! that answers my question. At the risk of sounding ungrateful, would you mind showing me how to add .each to the counter? thank you thank you thank!

Comment: You are very welcome! I do not believe you need to add `.each()` for the counter; however, please note that I did update my code so that references to the counter should retrieve the correct DOM element: `$(".current", currentFrame.next())`. (This updated reference occurs in two places in the code.)

Comment: Thank you again! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an id more than once. You currently have id="slideframe" in more than one spot. jQuery is able to see the first instance only. Try changing slideframe to a class.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Though if I change it to a class "$(".slideframe").children()" grabs every .image element on the page rather than the .slideframe divs immediate children.